# Probability coin toss question

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

In a 50:50 gambling game where you double your stake each time you guess the correct outcome, how many times harder would it be to guess the correct outcome 15 times in a row than 3 times in a row? I’m guessing it’s not 5x harder, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you mean: "What is the probability that you guess correctly 15 times in a row, divided by the probability that you guess correctly 3 times?"

Comment: I guess I am looking to conceptualise the difference in difficulty between guessing correctly 3 times in a row vs guessing correctly 15 times in a row. Would that just be the odds of 15 correct guesses in a row (2^15) divided by 3 correct guesses in a row (2^3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guessing the outcome $15$ times in a row, it is $(\frac{1}{2})^{15} = \frac{1}{2^{15}}$. For guessing the outcome $3$ times in a row, it is $(\frac{1}{2})^{3} = \frac{1}{8}$. Therefore, the amount of times harder it would be to guess an outcome $15$ times in a row as opposed to $3$ times in a row is ${2^{12}} = \fbox{4096}$ times harder.

Comment: Thank you! It is a lot harder than I thought. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Roberto, you're welcome!